# Dropdown links in summernote is not working properly

Tags: summernote

Summernote dropdown doesn't work with Bootstrap 5, please help with the below code. The error says Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.tooltip.

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mt-3">
    <div id="summernote"></div>
            </div>
          </div>  
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote(
    {height:300,
    }
  );

  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
  });
</script>
</body></html>
```

```
Codepen link https://codepen.io/murli-vm/pen/XWpLqpp
```